# JavaScript addEventListener doesn't work for some reason

Tags: javascript, events, dom, toggle

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm trying to add an event listener to my button.
Here is my HTML (Yes, the script is loaded after the button):

```
<html>
   <body>
      <button>Click me</button>
   <body>

   <script src="experimenting2.js"></script>
</html>
```

And Here's my JS code:

```
alert("Connected");
var body = document.getElementByTagName("body");
var button = document.getElementByTagName("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert("Clicked");

   body.style.background = "pink";

});
```

The first alert at the beginning of the JS file gets triggered when I load up the page but the second one inside the addEventListener doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Namely, `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByTagName is not a function`

Comment: Edit: George Bailey answered

Comment: @BoSsYyY Please check the answers and give the tick mark to the answer that provided the correct solution to your issue. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like `document.getElementByTagName("body");` It is `document.getElementsByTagName("body");` which returns you the collection and you need to loop through this collection to attach events to each node in it

Or you can use `document.querySelector('body')` to select the body and `document.querySelector('button')` to  select the button

Read here about [**`document.querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
alert("Connected");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert("Clicked");

   body.style.background = "pink";

});
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <button>Click me</button>
   <body>

   
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The method signature to get elements by tag name is

```
getElementsByTagName(..)
```

But you are using

```
getElementByTagName(..)
```

Any way in the following code

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

You are getting a collection of buttons and not a single button. Where do you want to add the EventListener?
A better way can be to access the element by Id by assigning id to the button in HTML

```
var button = document.getElementById("someid");
```

Otherwise, you can also try as you have only single button which you are intending to add EventListener to

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementByTagName` should be `getElementsByTagName`

And you can use `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByTagName` like this:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
```

And you don't have to assign a variable for the body. Just reference it with `document.body` like this:

```
document.body.style.background = "pink";
```

---

So your complete code should look like this:

```js
alert("Connected");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert("Clicked");

   document.body.style.background = "pink";

});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/2cscc5ka/

Answer (score 2):

actually the problem is that you are calling `getElementByTagName` and it is `getElementsByTagName`. also it returns an array of items.

check the working sample:

```js
console.log("Connected");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  body.style.background = "pink";

});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button>Click me</button>

  <body>

    <script src="experimenting2.js"></script>

</html>
```

Also check that it will be easier using the `id` property and the function `getElementById`

```js
console.log("Connected");
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  body.style.background = "pink";

});
```

```html
<html>

<body id="body">
  <button id="button">Click me</button>

  <body>

    <script src="experimenting2.js"></script>

</html>
```